# Set different x-axis breaks for plot and table in ggsurvplot (survminer package in R)

Tags: r, survminer

I can set different x-axis breaks in ggplot and survminer::ggsurvplot. I am currently setting this by using `break.time.by = 365.25 / 12` (monthly). However, I need to set axis labels for the **table** every 12 months (to meet formatting requirements that I can't change).  I tried formatting just the table component of the overall plot and using scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(values here)) but that didn't work. I get a message saying that `Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will replace the existing scale.`

Comment: I believe the output of ggsurvplot is a ggplot object. If so, you can add to it a second axis as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales

Answer (score 2):

You can substitute a scale in the object created by `ggsurvplot`, which is a list-like object containing two `ggplot` objects (among other things). One of these `ggplot` objects is called `table`. You can either add a second `scale_x_continuous` to that (and get the warning about adding a second scale), or just over-write the original.

As an example, we'll use one of the built in data sets from the `survival` package:

```r
library(survival)
library(survminer)

fit3 <- survfit( Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = colon)

ggsurv <- ggsurvplot(fit3, data = colon,
  fun = "cumhaz", conf.int = TRUE,
  risk.table = TRUE, risk.table.col="strata",
  ggtheme = theme_bw())

ggsurv
```

[image]

We can find out which scale object is the x-scale by doing:

```r
x <- which(ggsurv$table$scales$find("x"))
```

And over-write it with our own scale. For example, we can make breaks every 200 rather than every 1000 units:

```r
ggsurv$table$scales$scales[[x]] <- scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:15 * 200)
```

And our plot is now as we want it, with the new scale in the table's x axis:

```r
ggsurv
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>